# Validator.js Module not found - Can't resolve http in client

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, amadeus

I've got some trouble implementing the amadeus-node package into an angular 10 project.
As soon as I implement the following line

```
const Amadeus = require('amadeus');
```

I receive this error

> ERROR in ./node_modules/amadeus/lib/amadeus/client/validator.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '\node_modules\amadeus\lib\amadeus\client'

But the validator.js exists. Any tips to solve the problem?
By the way... some type definitions would be great ;)

**Edit**

I think I missunderstood the error message. But I'm still not sure what's wrong. I think the error occurs in validator.js and he's missing a module named 'http' in the path '\node_modules\amadeus\lib\amadeus\client'. But this makes no sense. He should use the http module of node.js. I'm using the latest LTS version of node.js (12.18.3).

Comment: i would suggest you to open an issue on the github project : https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-node/issues

Comment: yeah, that would have been my next step. But I was wondering if I'm using the package wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it seems I was using the package wrong. I opened an issue at the developers github page:

https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-node/issues/85

this was the response:

> Hey! Thanks for reporting this issue. The SDK is not designed to work on client-side frameworks like Angular (you can see that Angular cannot resolve the http-node dependency from amadeus-sdk) but on nodejs applications.
>
> By the way, we have never consumed the SDK within a Typescript
> application. I believe it's not going to work out-of-the-box as it
> needs to provide a type declaration file.